# Validating Form Using Custom Function

Tags: jquery

I am trying to validate a form to check if the inputs are empty or not at [THIS JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Proweb/462jr/1/)
I was able to validate the form successfully when I used the whole body of the `validateEmpty()` function directly inside the `.submit()` function but just to keep everthing organized I tried to put everything inside a function (`validateEmpty()`) and just call it through the `.submit()` function but for what ever reason the validation process is not working!

Here is the Code I have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
function validateEmpty(){
        var abort = false;
        $("div.err").remove();
        $(':input[required]').each(function() {
            if ($(this).val()==='') {
                $(this).parent().after('<div class="err">This is a Requierd Field</div>');
                abort = true;
            }
        }) 
        if (abort) { return false; } else { return true; }
}
$('#myform').submit(function() {
validateEmpty();
    })
});
```

can you please let me know what I am doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `validateEmpty` function returns `true` or `false` at its end, but on your event handler you never `return` it, so jQuery never gets that value. All you need is to add a `return` call to your handler:

```
$('#myform').submit(function() {
  return validateEmpty();
});
```

Also, note that you can pass the function directly if you don't need to do anything extra:

```
$('#myform').submit(validateEmpty);
```

---

As requested in the comments, here goes two a way to parameterize the `validateEmpty` function:

```
function validateEmpty($inputs) {
  var abort = false;
  $("div.err").remove();

  $inputs.each(function() {
    if ($(this).val()==='') {
        $(this).parent().after('<div class="err">This is a Requierd Field</div>');
        abort = true;
    }
  });

  if (abort) { return false; } else { return true; }
}

$("#myform").submit(function() {
  // Take the 'required' inputs inside #myform only
  var $inputs = $(this, "input[required]");
  return validateEmpty($inputs);
});
```

Comment: Ok it woks now thanks but honestly I didnt really understand what do you mean by "but you are not relaying it to jQuery"!

Comment: Sorry, I guess I was too terse. I just edited the answer, is it more clear now?

Comment: Great thanks for perfect explenation just a quick question, is there any way to pass parameter through the validateEmpty(); in a way that to not have the '$(':input[required]')' hard coded and select the targets on submit function something like this: '  return validateEmpty(':input[required]');' once again thanks for your perfect hints

Comment: Done! See if this helps

Answer (score 1):

Please add jquery framework in your jsfiddle example and try out

```
$('#myform').submit(function() {
  return validateEmpty();
});
```